# Optimisation of O(n4) complexity to O(n) in PHP nested for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, time-complexity

I am writing one logic to iterate numbers first and then additional logic to putting them into particular subset of array.

What does this code do :

1. Code accept first $n
2. its create array of $n number from 1 to $n
3. Then started converting to subset of $main_array to possible one like 
   ['1'] [1,2] [1,2,3] [2] [2,3] [3] etc. [same like this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subarraysubstring-vs-subsequence-and-programs-to-generate-them/)
4. After creating subset i am counting those some subset which satisfy condition
5. Condition is xyz[0] should not come in subset with abc[0] vice versa xyz[i] should not come in subset abc[i]. Example 2 and 3 is coming subset then dont count that subset, same 1 and 4 is coming then dont count

here is my nested for loop :

```
$n = 1299;
$main_array = range(1,$n); 
$counter = 0; 
$count = sizeof($abc);  // $abc and $xyz size will same always. 
$abc = [2,1];
$xyz = [3,4];

for ($i=0; $i <$n; $i++) {  
         for($j = $i;$j < $n; $j++){  
            $interval_array = array();
          for ($k = $i; $k <= $j; $k++){
                array_push($interval_array,$main_array[$k]);
          }
           $counter++;
           for ($l=0; $l < $count ; $l++) {
                //if block here to additional condition using in_array() php function. which do $counter--
                if(in_array($abc[$l], $interval_array) && 
                 in_array($xyz[$l], $interval_array)){ 
                     $counter--;
                     break;
                 } 
             } 
         }
    }
```

`$main_array` i have to create on the spot after receiving `$n` values.

Following is cases :

1. when running `$n = 4` its run in 4s
2. when running `$n = 1200 or 1299 or more than 1000` its run in `60s-123s`

Expected execution timing is 9s. I reduce from 124s to 65s by removing function calling inside for loop but its not coming to point.

Expectation of code is if i have array like

```
$array = [1,2,3];
```

then

subset need to generate :

```
[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[2],[2,3],[3]
```

Any help in this ?

Comment: Give us your original task so we can understand what is wanted here.

Comment: this is task only i cant give exact details. but this exactly same which i am trying to do. You can run this check how much execution time is coming for this. I motive to reduce execution time till 9 seconds. for $n > 1200

Comment: I cannot understand what is wanted from the task. What this code should do. I understand what you want, to reduce the time, but what does the code do?

Comment: In your inner most loop - you have `for ($l=0; $l < $count ; $l++) {` where `$count=5;`, but the arrays `$abc` and `$xyz` only contain 2 values, so shouldn't `$count=2;` be used, or `$count=count($abc);`

Comment: mistakenly added. correct that statement now check. @NigelRen

Comment: The only further suggestion would be to assume that if the blocking parts are in this array, they will be in every combination of the inner loop (after all it just adds values and the blocked combination will never disappear). To stop any further checks - change the `break` to be `break 2` to stop the next level loop as well.

Comment: Its wokring for 1299 number. have u think further can improve because for more than 3000 its giving 123 seconds.

Comment: any more help in this to optimise ? @NigelRen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to test performance against your experience, but this solution removes one of the loops.

The way you repeatedly build `$interval_array` is not needed, what this code does is to just add the new value from the main array on each `$j` loop.  This array is then reset only in the outer loop and so it just keeps the last values and adds 1 extra value each time...

```
for ($i=0; $i <$n; $i++) {
    $interval_array = array();
    for($j = $i;$j < $n; $j++){
        array_push($interval_array,$main_array[$j]);
        // Check output
        echo implode(",", $interval_array)."\n";

        $counter++;
        for ($l=0; $l < $count ; $l++) {
            if(in_array($abc[$l], $interval_array) && 
             in_array($xyz[$l], $interval_array)){ 
                 $counter--;
                 break 2;
             } 
        }
    }
}
```

adding "\n" to better understanding for subset flow.

Comment: for ($k = $i; $k <= $j; $k++){ 
                array_push($interval_array,$main_array[$k]);
           } this code gives me [1] [1,2] [1,2,3] [2] [2,3][3] etc  so your code will not serve my purpose.

Comment: Can you check what my code generates in `$interval_array`.

Comment: Your code gives array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(4)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
} which is not expected . Check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subarraysubstring-vs-subsequence-and-programs-to-generate-them/

Comment: I've added a line to the code which should show what the array contains, I get `1/1,2/1,2,3/1,2,3,4/2/2,3/2,3,4/3/3,4/4/`.

Comment: please check my question details. I have added expectation.

Comment: Which as far as I can tell is what I generate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203017/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: its woking checking all test cases. But its reduce to 32 seconds. my target is to move 9s. i have reduce more complexity. Its coming upto 32seconds. Any further changes ?

Comment: Can you define how you are removing items - your code uses `$abc` and `$xyz`, but can you give an example of how it works.

Comment: added in description move discussion to chat

Comment: accepting this answer no further optimisation can happen. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime


N = list(range(1, int(input("N:")) + 1))

affected_list = list(map(int, input("affected_list").split()))

poisoned_list = list(map(int, input("poisoned_list").split()))

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

exclude_list = list(map(list, list(zip(affected_list, poisoned_list))))

final_list = []

for i in range(0, len(N)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(N) + 1):
        if N[i:j] not in exclude_list:
            final_list.append(N[i:j])

print(final_list)
end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Total Time: ", (end_time - start_time).seconds)
```